# Sending Email through Smtp

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

i'm unable to send mail, exception "Failure sending mail"

 what should i do to correct the code?

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("yourmail@mail.com", ToEmail);
StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();
sbEmailBody.Append("<b>Registration Approval for</b></br>");
sbEmailBody.Append(InstituteName + "<br/><br/>");
sbEmailBody.Append("Thanks for your registration ");
sbEmailBody.Append("<br/>");

mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
mailMessage.Subject = "Confirmation Mail!";
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.com", 587);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    UserName = "yourmailn@mail.com",
    Password = " "
};

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: first you should correct the question, not your code. "unable to send email" is way too broad, debug the code and post what exception is thrown first.

Comment: Exception is " Failure sending mail."

Comment: are you trying to send the email from "mail.com" or the smtp is located on your network and this is just a substitute for the example?

Comment: yes i'm trying to send mail from mail.com. and i'm using localhost for testing .

Comment: try adding the line `smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;`

Comment: Still the same problem . it does not work

Comment: are you sure all the information is correct? have you tried sending it through a non ssl port 25?

Comment: yea information is correct.

Comment: im not sure mail.com allows doing that. try sending an email from live/google/yahoo and see if you succeed. your exception if you expand it twice, you will see the inner exception is "server did not respond". i think mail.com blocks smtp access